# Hot reload context datasource

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I my spring application running on a Tomcat 7 server, every client has his own schema of database.
All datasources are defined on a applicationContext-dataSources.xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="DataSource" class="es.beyond.conexion.CustomerRoutingDataSource">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="client1" value-ref="client1" />
            <entry key="client2" value-ref="client2" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="erpmodularizado" />
</bean>

<bean id="SessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="es.beyond" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="es.beyond.conexion.AuditLogInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="client1" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/client1" />
    <property name="user" value="client1" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM dual" />
</bean>

<bean id="client2" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/client2" />
    <property name="user" value="client2" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM dual" />
</bean>
```

I want that if a client is registered in the application, the app write the new schema on xml (I also has a list of empty schema on my database to be asigned), and then reload de applicationContext without restart the tomcat server.

Is this possible? Or I'm trying some crazy?

Thanks

Comment: You don't want that. What would happen to all other users of your application if you suddenly restart the application. Instead find another way to, persistently, store your datasource configuration (like in a master database) and use that to configure datasources on the fly/lazily.

Comment: Writing new schema file will not create a new client object. You have to use Java code to register a new client bean with the new details.

Comment: The idea was load the applicationContext-dataSources.xml as a resource from a external folder of webapp to prevent this problem if tomcat restart. @M.Deinum I always has loaded datasource in spring from xml. How I can do this? or Where I can watch an example? Thanks